# unpickling model file python scikit-learn(Pipeline(memory=None, steps=None, verbose=None))

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, pipeline

I am trying to convert pickle file from `Python 2` to `Python 3` using below code:

```
import os
import dill
import pickle
import argparse


def convert(old_pkl):
    """
    Convert a Python 2 pickle to Python 3
    """
    # Make a name for the new pickle
    new_pkl = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(old_pkl))[0]+"_p3.pkl"

    # Convert Python 2 "ObjectType" to Python 3 object
    dill._dill._reverse_typemap["ObjectType"] = object

    # Open the pickle using latin1 encoding
    with open(old_pkl, "rb") as f:
        loaded = pickle.load(f, encoding="bytes")

    # Re-save as Python 3 pickle
    with open(new_pkl, "wb") as outfile:
        pickle.dump(loaded, outfile)
```

Pickling worked fine. But, the problem is when i tried to print the output of `Python3` pickled file instead of showing below:

```
model = Pipeline([('count', CountVectorizer())
])

print(model)
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None)])
```

it's showing below:

```
Pipeline(memory=None, steps=None, verbose=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

While unpickling the file i used `encoding` as `bytes` instead of `latin1`.

## Open the pickle using latin1 encoding

```
with open(old_pkl, "rb") as f:
    loaded = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
```

and everything worked fine. For better clarification refer [this](https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/convert-py2-pickles-to-py3/)